# How to add more fields after submission?

Tags: forms

I was wondering how to add more fields to a form after submitting that form.
So the form should have these fields for example:

- Name (textfield)
- City (select list)
- Find (button)

and then when user performs the submission, the result page should look like this:

- Name (textfield)
- City (select list)
- Gender (radio buttons) <-- so they can refine the search by gender
- Find (button)

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a submit handler to the button that updates some specific variable in $form_state so you can determine the "step" of the form. 
Plus, a `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` to rebuild the form.

Assuming you are using Drupal 7, a hook_menu or hook_block_view (or any other function) is calling drupal_get_form function with "my_form" as argument.

```
function my_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Name'),
  );
  $form['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('City'),
    '#options' => array(
      1 => t('Kandy'), 2 => t('Anuradhapura'),
    ),
  );
  if (isset($form_state['next_step']) && $form_state['next_step']) {
    $form['gender'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Gender'),
      '#options' => array(
        'm' => t('Male'), 'f' => t('Female'),
      ),
    );
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Find'),
  );
  return $form;
}

function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['next_step'] = TRUE; // You can also change this to FALSE in validate function to prevent the gender from appearing. 
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; // Don't forget this!

  // Do other stuff here.
}
```

Note how I conditionally added the gender form element, and how the submit handler sets that value.

When the form is loaded for the first time (with empty `$form_state`), the condition to add the gender element will be `FALSE`, so no element added. 
Then, the form submit handler adds the values so in the next form rebuild, element gets included. 
Tricky part is the `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` part.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do some kind of multi-step form.
This is generally not a trivial task, but it can be done.
There are a quite a few tutorials around on how to do it, but you should look at the official Docs for it first [here](http://drupal.org/node/101707).

Another good resource for multi-step is the "Form Wizard" component of the CTools suite, which can be found [here](http://drupal.org/project/ctools).

Hope this is helpful. One of my upcoming projects concerns this, so I am trying to learn all I can about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be proper place to use AHAH framework. [Here](http://drupal.org/node/348475) and [here](http://drupal.org/node/331941) you have doc about it.

Comment: Thank you but I guess AHAH is useful when you want to add elements dynamically without loading the page (more like Ajax stuff)? if I am right, I need to add the element after the page is reloaded and form has been submitted

Comment: AJAX or #states can do the hide/show stuff in the forms but this is more of a multistep form.